# SQL Server REGEX zipcode not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have this code which check if the column `postcode` is valid. The **working** check constraint looks like this:

```
UPPER(postcode) LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

So, again, this code works. But when I change it to:

```
UPPER(postcode) LIKE '[1-9][0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}'
```

then it doesn't work. Everywhere I read about regex they say this is how to check it, but apparently not. Anyone know why it isn't working?

Comment: Because it is not a regex, it is a wildcard pattern. Wildcards do not support limiting quantifiers.

Comment: SQL Server does not have native support for regular expressions.  And, as far as I know, no database uses `LIKE` for regular expression matching.

Comment: Ok thanks :D. I'm kinda new at this as you might have noticed ;) Is the first way ok?